# Issue passing the correct item to an other function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, prototype, settimeout

Here's my problem:

```
var slide;
$$('#slides li').each(function(i, n) {
    slide = i;
    setTimeout("initiateSlide()",n * 500)                     
});
function initiateSlide(){
    i = slide;
    alert(i); // pretty much alerts the last one 5 times
}
```

I expect to `initiateSlide()` with 5 different slides, instead I only get the last one 5 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the global variable (slide) that you are referencing in the initiateSlide() function is set to the last one by the time the function runs. You probably want to use closures to maintain the state of the variable. Like this:

```
$$('#slides li').each(function(i, n) {
    setTimeout(function() { initiateSlide(i); }, n * 500)
});
function initiateSlide(i){
    alert(i);
}
```

Note - This also removes the need for the global entirely

Comment: +1: Thanks! This solved the different problem I was having passing objects to setTimeout functions :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to get rid of the global variables and pass each slide within the loop as an argument to your `initiateSlide` function:

```
$$('#slides li').each(function(slide, n) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    initiateSlide(slide);
  }, n * 500)                     
});

function initiateSlide(slide){
  alert(slide);
}​
```

In your example, the `each` loop ended before any `setTimeout` callback was executed, your `initiateSlide` function was being invoked using the last iterated element.